# loop for loading files and assigning variables

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop

I am brand new to python and am working on a school project. I was able to write the code to make my project work. However, I realize the way I did it is terribly inefficient and that there is probably a better way to store and work with the data in a 3D numpy array. I want to learn a better way to write code like this.

I have tried searching but I don't understand enough python to know what to search for or find the answers.

Question 1: How would I rewrite the code below to use a for loop to do the repetitive parts?

Question 2: Should I have used a 3D numpy array instead of assigning data to array_2001, array_2002, etc.? If so how would I do the array math using it?

```
from pyhdf.SD
import SD, SDC
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

#Number of images
max_samples = 18

#Values to filter with
exclude_below = 0
exclude_above = 100
min_threshold = 40
max_threshold = 100

#path to directory containing hdf files
file_path = '/Data/2018_2001_georef_MODIS/'

#Get a list of all the .hdf files in the directory
MODIS_files = glob.glob(file_path + '*.hdf')

#Get 2001 data
file = SD(MODIS_files[0], SDC.READ)
datasets_dic = file.datasets()
sds_obj = file.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover') # select sds
Array_2001 = np.array(sds_obj.get()) # get sds data

# Get 2002 data
file = SD(MODIS_files[1], SDC.READ)
sds_obj = file.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover') # select sds
Array_2002 = np.array(sds_obj.get()) # get sds data
```

**#Repeat over and over for the rest of the files**

```
#Get 2018 data
file = SD(MODIS_files[17], SDC.READ)
sds_obj = file.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover') # select sds
Array_2018 = np.array(sds_obj.get()) # get sds data
#print ('Array_2018  :', Array_2018)


#Create a boolean mask where 'true' means there is snow on
# on the pixel within the thresholds

snow_mask_2001 = (Array_2001 >= min_threshold) & (Array_2001 <=      max_threshold)
snow_mask_2002 = (Array_2002 >= min_threshold) & (Array_2002 <= max_threshold)
snow_mask_2003 = (Array_2003 >= min_threshold) & (Array_2003 <= max_threshold)
```

**#Repeat over and over for the rest of the files**

```
snow_mask_2018 = (Array_2018 >= min_threshold) & (Array_2018 <= max_threshold)


non_snow_2001 = (Array_2001 > exclude_above) | (Array_2001 < exclude_below)
non_snow_2002 = (Array_2002 > exclude_above) | (Array_2002 < exclude_below)
non_snow_2003 = (Array_2003 > exclude_above) | (Array_2003 < exclude_below)
```

**#Repeat over and over for the rest of the files**

```
non_snow_2018 = (Array_2018 > exclude_above) | (Array_2018 < exclude_below)
```

Next, I converted the boolean 'true, false' arrays to ones and zeros. 
(code not shown for brevity).

```
#Sum the number of snow days per pixel
snow_days = snow_mask_2001 + snow_mask_2002 + snow_mask_ ...      snow_mask_2018

#sum the number of days with a 'non-snow' reading per pixel
no_reading_days = non_snow_2001 + non_snow_2002 + non_snow_2003 + …     non_snow_2017 + non_snow_2018
```

There's more to my code after this point but it's non-repetative.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
In particular, I recommend that you work through a basic Python tutorial, so you learn how to use the language building blocks.

Comment: What is the file format? hdf5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through the files you stored in your list, and append everything to one big numpy array. On that numpy array your can do your masking...

```
#path to directory containing hdf files
file_path = '/Data/2018_2001_georef_MODIS/'

#Get a list of all the .hdf files in the directory
MODIS_files = glob.glob(file_path + '*.hdf')

#?? should be the size of your array.
arr = np.empty((0,??), float)

for file_name in MODIS_files:
    file = SD(MODIS_files[file_name ], SDC.READ)
    datasets_dic = file.datasets()
    sds_obj = file.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover') # select sds
    arr = np.append(arr, np.array(sds_obj.get()), axis=0)
```